# Prime NG - Carousel navigation Indicator need custom dots

Tags: angular, carousel, primeng

I am developing prime Ng Carousel, want to change the number of dots for navigation.
if there are 6 Mini cards, I need 6 dots for carousel. Minimum 4 mini card should display.

Is there a way to develop this with primeNG

PrimeNg basic Carousel [Example](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng-v15-lts/carousel#basic)

Answer (score 1):

If you have 6 mini cards and want to have 4 mini cards displayed, why do you want to have 6 dots ?

You will only need 3 dots max in this case

Comment: I want to highlight each card on dot click
If first dot is clicked it should highlight first card

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't see any easy way to do this with this component. It should be posible if you only display one mini card at a time but it is not what you want.

Answer (score 1):

The number of indicators is calculated automatically by the carousel component, We can not customize

Please check [totalDots function](https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/blob/3291d844f1e30debe6c5801741629908266edfeb/src/app/components/carousel/carousel.ts#L624C5-L624C14)